# How to use two class with the same name in different packages?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

How can I access two classes with the same name in different packages?

```
foo.bar.myClass.class
```

and

```
foo.myClass.class
```

All of this in the same class

```
@TestRunner(Suite.class)
@SuiteTest({bar.myClass.class, myClass.class})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you will have to import one and other you will be writting fully qualified path

for example in your code:

```
import foo.bar.myClass;

.
.
.
myClass ob; // this  will refer to foo.bar.myClass 
foo.myClass ob1 ;//this  will refer to foo.myClass
```

Comment: @Drahakar Why reverted back it as answer  ? let us know if you want more info so that we can help more

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the fully qualified names of the classes.

```
 foo.bar.myClass myvar;
 foo.myClass anothervar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without imports:

```
@TestRunner(Suite.class)
@SuiteTest({foo.bar.myClass.class, foo.myClass.class})
```