# Import two packages that have the same classe but also other classes

Tags: java, package

If I have two different packages that have classes with the same name, and I want specifically to call class1 from package1 I would use:

```
import package1.class1;
import package2.*;
```

But what if I also want all the other classes of package1? Would the correct code be:

```
import package1.*;
import package2.*;
```

and then

```
package1.class1 teste = new package1.class1();
```

?

Comment: Yes it is the correct way. It was also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368120/how-to-use-two-class-with-the-same-name-in-different-packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just import the two packages with a wildcard, you will get a compilation error when trying to use the unqualified class name, as it would be ambiguous:

```
import package1.*;
import package2.*;

// snipped

// compilation error. 
// No way to tell if you mean package1.class1 or package2.class1
class1 c = new class1();
```

One way around this is to fully qualify your usage:

```
// No ambiguity, so no error.
package1.class1 c = new package1.class1();
```

Funnily enough, another way around this is to add an **additional** import for that specific class. This explicit import takes precedence on any wildcard import, and resolves any ambiguity:

```
import package1.*;
import package2.*;
import package1.class1;

// snipped

// This is an instance of package1.class1.
class1 c = new class1();
```

Comment: +1 this kind of additional ways around are one of biggest reasons why I am on SO :)